# Adding a click listener to the Drag-Sort-Listview library

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listfragment

I've implemented this library based off a listfragment, and its implementation is very similar to this code sample on the library's github repo:

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/blob/master/demo/src/com/mobeta/android/demodslv/DSLVFragment.java

My question is, how do I implement a click listener?

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mobeta.android.dslv"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    dslv:drag_handle_id="@drawable/bg_handle"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
    dslv:float_background_color="@color/blue"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    dslv:use_default_controller="false" />
```

And this is how I've tried to create a click listener, but it doesn't respond:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDslv = (DragSortListView) inflater.inflate(getLayout(), container, false);

mController = buildController(mDslv);
mDslv.setFloatViewManager(mController);
mDslv.setOnTouchListener(mController);
mDslv.setDragEnabled(dragEnabled);


SimpleFloatViewManager simpleFloatViewManager = new SimpleFloatViewManager(mDslv);
simpleFloatViewManager.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mDslv.setFloatViewManager(simpleFloatViewManager);

mDslv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("Clicked!");
    }
});


return mDslv;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use at the same time `OnItemClickListener` and `OnTouchListener`.
You have **3 options**, just choose one you like:
**1)** Give up `OnTouchListener`
**2)** Return false from `onTouch()` when you need click to be generated
**3)** Generate click yourself `mDslv.performClick()` in `onTouch()`when required